# Azure Keyvault to be accessed by service principals in various subscriptions

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-keyvault

Creating a global key vault that can be access from other subscriptions.

Can a key vault created in 1 subscription be accessed by Service Principals created in other subscriptions.

Answer (score 0):

Service Principals aren't linked to Subscriptions. Service Principals are an AAD concept.

Subscriptions can trust one (and only one) AAD.

If the Subscriptions trust the AAD that the Service Principals are created in, then you can allow the Service Principals to access the KeyVault.